# Update All Fields which is don't have the same name in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update all fields in Document based on req.body.

In this case, the Schema are not defined in Mongoose. So, I can fill freely what will be in post to schema

For example, I've 2 Scheme like this in the Document:

Schema 1:

```
{
 "name": {
  "type": "text",
  "value": "Afdallah"
 },
 "item": {
  "type": "text",
  "value": "Books"
 }
}
```

And the other is like this

Schema 2:

```
{
 "name": {
  "type": "text",
  "value": "Afdallah"
 },
 "email": {
  "type": "email",
  "value": "afdallah.war@gmail.com"
 }
}
```

My question is, how to update all fields when they don't have same fields name?

I've try like this to update the fields.

```
const output = await Order.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
try {
  output.set(req.body);
  await output.save();
  res.send("Success Update");
} catch (err) {
  res.status(422).send(err);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, you can take advantage of `Object.assign` to duplicate your current data and merge it with upcoming data which is `req.body`.

```
const newData = Object.assign({}, output, req.body);

output = newData;
```